# How to use the date from date picker in jquery and catch it in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, date

In my code, if a user selects a date from the date picker which is a past date (ie. date before current date), I need to catch the date from the script part to php so that i can compare it with the dates stored in mysql database. Anybody having any clue for "how to get a date from the date picker and using it in php?" Even if ajax is to be used for it, how? I am very new to ajax and jquery so please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to take a look at the jquery examples on their official page?

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, but i didn't go through them as of now

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using ajax. If you plan to use jquery take a look at jQuery.ajax() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

In PHP create a route on POST ex: http://[your-domain]/api/check-date where you can compare your dates and return a response.

On your datepicker define the onSelect option to call your php script on ajax http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect The code will look something like this:

```
$([your-selector]).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(date) {
          // create your ajax call here
          $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "http://[your-domain]/api/check-date", // your url
             data: { data: date }
          })
          .done(function( response ) {
             // do something when you get your response from php
          });
      }
});
```